# Passing Parameters to Jenkins Through Gitlab Merge Request

Tags: python, jenkins, gitlab

**My goal**: Run Python tests any time a merge request is made in Gitlab.

**The problem**: The entire regression takes too long, so I'd like to run a particular subset of tests based on some level on configuration. This requires me somehow passing "arguments" through Gitlab to Jenkins with each merge request. Say in the comment put "test/api" or something similar?

My only thought so far is to perhaps have a file that gets pushed with the commit that Jenkins can look at when it runs its jobs. This is one way to do it, but I feel like there has to be a better way and my searching hasn't yielded any results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing your own GitLab instance, you can have a hook parsing the comment for extracting that parameter: a comment is better than a file, because this is about metadata, not data (source code).
Another option would be to push a [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes), which is also a metadata which can be added on top of commit.

The issue, though, is that there is no hook for merge request, not is there any webhook ([issue 42570](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42570)). [Issues 53716](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53716) proposes a somewhat convoluted alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The [GitLab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin) allows you to get info from a GitLab merge request hook. You'll get the git commit hash in the `gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit` variable and using it you can get the commit message and parse it.